# Suggestions on transferring only "new" rows into Snowflake using Azure Data Factory?

Tags: sql, azure, sharepoint, pipe, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have roughly 10 Sharepoint Lists that I am trying to pipe into Snowflake using ADF as the pipeline service. I plan on running each pipeline once a day and want to only take the newest Sharepoint List entries. Currently, whenever the pipelines run they copy over what is already in Snowflake duplicating it all.

Is there a way to not have duplicates? A couple ideas came to mind:

1. Create an intermediary table in Azure
2. Delete possible duplicates within Snowflake (I don't think this can be automated though)
3. Delete current data in Snowflake to be replaced every time the pipeline runs (not cost effective)

I am new to data processing and the web has been a good resource so far, but this seems to be a rather niche question.

Comment: Are there any fields in Sharepoint that could be used to determine "new" records e.g. created date or updated date?

Comment: There is a field on each pertaining to report date, yes. Each entry for each list in Sharepoint comes from a form that is filled out periodically.